# Display x-axis labels with dates when using geom_smooth() and geom_point() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data.frame:

```
prv <- data.frame(mese = as.Date(c( "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01" ,"2020-11-01","2020-12-01" ,
                                    "2021-01-01" ,"2021-02-01", "2021-03-01" ,"2021-04-01")),
                  cumulato = c(150  ,200  ,280  ,400, 550 ,800 ,1200 , 2000),
                  x_value = 1:8)
```

The problem appears when I use geom_smooth() togheter with geom_point() and want to display dates in xlabels:

```
g <- ggplot(data =  prv, mapping = aes(x= mese, y = cumulato )) + 
    geom_smooth(data =  prv, mapping = aes(x= x_value, y = cumulato), method="lm", formula= (y ~ exp(x))) +
    geom_point( size = 3)
```

I got the error: 
*Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied*

How can I get x-axis labels with dates (i.e. mese variable), even if I use geom_smooth() with formula argument? 
Of course I cannot use  **x= mese** in geom_smooth Aesthetic because of formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you may get the desired result when taking `mese` as factor with levels 1 to 8 just as `x_value`?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data =  prv, mapping = aes(x = as.factor(mese), y = cumulato )) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = x_value, y = cumulato), method = "lm", formula = y ~ exp(x))
```

#### Data

```
prv <-
  data.frame(
    mese = as.Date(c("2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-12-01",
                     "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01")),
    cumulato     = c(150  , 200  , 280  , 400, 550 , 800 , 1200 , 2000),
    x_value = 1:8
  )
```

[image]